Truncated transcription in chirp model
I am using google.cloud.speech_v2 client library for python to get the
transcription of a short (< 1 min) audio in spanish. It works fine with model = "long", language code = "es-US". Same audio with "chirp" gives only the first part of the transcription.
I am using chirp because I need automatic punctuation. Tried different audios and different chirp model (chirp 2) with the same result.
Here is my code:
def transcribe_chirp(
audio_file: str):

client = SpeechClient(
    client_options=ClientOptions(
        api_endpoint="us-central1-speech.googleapis.com",
    )
)
with open(audio_file, "rb") as f:
    audio_content = f.read()

config = cloud_speech.RecognitionConfig(
    auto_decoding_config=cloud_speech.AutoDetectDecodingConfig(),
    language_codes=["es-US"],
    model="chirp",
    features=cloud_speech.RecognitionFeatures(
        # Enable automatic punctuation
        enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
        max_alternatives = 2,
        enable_word_time_offsets=True
    ),
)
request = cloud_speech.RecognizeRequest(
    recognizer=f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/recognizers/_",
    config=config,
    content=audio_content,
)
response = client.recognize(request=request)

for result in response.results:
    print(f"Transcript: {result.alternatives[0].transcript}")

return response


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
